# Google Calender API v3 avoid creating event if one already is created for that date/time ( C# .NET)

Tags: c#, .net, google-api, google-calendar-api

How can I check if I will end up making events at the same time in the Google Calendar API v3 in a certain calendar?

Google didn't give any help and the API documentation is consfusing and lacks .NET examples.

Comment: Can you add any details like: code used, error problem encountered? [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) Show the community what you have tried.

Comment: Also there's a difference between whether an event is unique or not, and whether a day is clear.   Generally in ics world events are identified by their UID.    For google see https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events#iCalUID

Comment: @anmari yeah ok thanks for that i'd rather not store uids, these event should only exist once per day i can just check if the day is clear

Answer (score 0):

I found that you can get all the events on a calendar with this: 
https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/calendar/v3/csharp/latest/classGoogle_1_1Apis_1_1Calendar_1_1v3_1_1EventsResource.html#aad662ad7f7ba3a29b0264cbdcec9f722

Then I could get these events into a list in C# with this code

```
List<Event> list = service.Events.List(calenderID).Execute().Items.ToList();
```

Then you iterate and see if it matches

```
foreach (Event e in list)
{
    if ( e.Start.DateTime == shift.start && e.End.DateTime == shift.end )
    {
        // Event conflicts
        safe = false; break;
    }
}
```